# Sort the table td having same text in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get an idea how we can sort the table having the same text in td

e.g I have a below table

```
Column 1     Column 2
    A           test1           
    B           test2
    C           test3
    D           test1
    E           test4
    F           test3
```

I want an output something like below

```
Column 1     Column 2
    A           test1           
    D           test1
    C           test3
    F           test3
    B           test2
    E           test4
```

Why I want to sort it in this way so that I can do the rowspan easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO** http://jsbin.com/sowudefaho/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var bText = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text();

    if (aText > bText){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (aText < bText){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

you can sort the table column using sort function

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fky56vao/2/)

```
    var trs = $("table tbody tr").sort((a,b)=> {return $(a).find("td:nth(1)").text().localeCompare($(b).find("td:nth(1)").text())})
    $("table tbody").empty().append(trs)
```

First,  select all tr rows

Second, sort each element by second td's text

Then, clear all child nodes in tbody and append sorted trs